# JQuery Ajax/laravel form submit not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've been trying some stuff with Ajax and laravel, I've tried a lot at this point and have no idea what is going wrong. I can't seem to get the form data (that's what this is mainly about). If ANYONE is able to help, it'd be great. Here's the code, and thanks in advance.

```
$('.bier').on('click', bier);
$('.delete-check-close').on('click', closeDelete);
$('.delete-check-show').on('click', showDelete);
$('.message').on('click', closeMessage);
hideMessage();

$('form.page').on('submit', bier);

function bier() {
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
    console.log(url);
    console.log(form);

    console.log('bier');
    console.log(form.find('input').serialize());
    console.log('/bier');
    var wtf = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'json',
        data: form.serialize(),
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data);

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            var data = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);

            console.log(data);

            if (data.errors) {
                console.log(data.errors);

                $.each( data.errors, function( key, value ) {
                    console.log(key);
                    console.log(value);

                    if(key.length > 0) {
                        var $error = $('td.' + key);
                        $error.removeClass('hidden');
                        $error.addClass('visible');
                        $error.html(value);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log('======================================== error');

                console.dir(jqXHR);
                console.dir(textStatus);
                console.dir(errorThrown);
            }
        }
    });

   return false;
}
});
```

Comment: It is my form, and I've figured out that there actually is an error , it just didn't show. Here's the error: 
POST 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
{message: "The given data was invalid." , errors : {...}}

In errros: it just shows every field from my form

Comment: Show us the server-side code, something is wrong with the validation logic probably. Are you using custom validators? Also it seems that you are sending the data as JSON but still using form.serialize(). You could try to serialize it with JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
  $('form.page').on('submit', function() { 
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
    console.log(url);
    console.log(form); 
    console.log('bier');
    console.log(form.find('input').serialize());
    console.log('/bier');
    var wtf = new FormData(form); 
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'json',
        data: form.serialize(),
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data);

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            var data = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);

            console.log(data);

            if (data.errors) {
                console.log(data.errors);

                $.each( data.errors, function( key, value ) {
                    console.log(key);
                    console.log(value);

                    if(key.length > 0) {
                        var $error = $('td.' + key);
                        $error.removeClass('hidden');
                        $error.addClass('visible');
                        $error.html(value);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log('======================================== error');
                console.dir(jqXHR);
                console.dir(textStatus);
                console.dir(errorThrown);
            }
        }
    }); 
   return false; 
});
```